# i run code to visualize artificial neural network visualization but error occurred

Tags: python

I run above mentioned code to visualize artificial neural network

```
from ann_visualizer.visualize import ann_viz;
ann_viz(ann, title="My first neural network")
```

but suffered the following error,

```
AttributeError: module 'keras.layers' has no attribute 'core'
```

Comment: `ann_visualizer` has not been updated in 6 years.  The `keras` module has changed since then.  There is no easy fix unless you want to dig into the code to fix it.